# Remove Dynamic Page JFace Wizard

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am adding new dynamic pages during running JFace wizard, by override the `getNext` method

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage()
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {   
        MyPage dynamic = new MyPage("dynamic"+i)
        wizard.addPage(dynamic);
    }
    return dynamic0;
}
```

Is there an option to remove all the dynamic pages in the next time the flow go through `getNextPage()` method.

Comment: its just example that i want to return the first page that i create

Comment: You should always post code, that would compile. Maybe post a SSCCE (www.sscce.org)

Comment: The `Wizard` has a field `pages` which contains all the `IWIzardPage`s. If you implement your own `Wizard` you could create a method `clear()` which deletes and disposes all the `IWizardPage`s in the `pages` list.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, pages are created in advance to enable the wizard to calculate it's maximum size. Adding pages "on the fly" can create issues in this area.

Having said this, there is no way of getting to the "pages" field which contains the pages to remove a page from this list.

One alternative is to "flag" the page as inactive and skip it during getNextPage() calculation.

Something like (this is getNextPage from IWizard):

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage(IWizardPage pPage)
{
    MyPage myPage = (MyPage) super.getNextPage(pPage);
    while(myPage != null && myPage.isInactive())
      {   
        myPage = (MyPage) super.getNextPage(myPage);
    }
    return myPage;
}
```